# I'm not able anymore to acces via ssh

Tags: authentication, ssh, server, ssh-keys

For a project, I need to access the faculty server
Remotely through ssh after connecting the faculty VPN with my credentials.

Before,I log in quietly until recently with:

```
ssh my_name_user@147.163.26.244
```

it appeared to enter the password and entering the credentials I accessed the server (actually a virtual machine mounted on the server for me).

Now with the command above nothing happens and after waiting a bit I get:

```
ssh: connect to host 147.163.26.244 port 22: Connection timed out
```

What may have happened?
Yesterday I changed my password to access University services (mandatory after 3 months for security reasons). After doing so I had to change that new password in the VPN configurations and I was able to have access to the VPN and also to the server, until this all ok. From today at 13.00 this problem occurs.

Does anyone have any idea what this is all about?
(I'm on Ubuntu. The server(the virtual machine is a Lubuntu system))
Thanks for your attention.

**Update:**
The command

```
ping 147.163.26.244
```

gives me:

```
PING 147.163.26.244 (147.163.26.244) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

and

```
telnet 147.163.26.244 22
```

gives:

```
Trying 147.163.26.244...
```

and it remain running. What can I deduce?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ssh shows connection timeout its nothing to do with your credentials. It hasn't go to the authentication level but failing before that itself.

First of all check if the IP is accessible from you machine using Ping (hoping ICMP should be allowed by the Firewall).

```
ping server_ip
```

If it shows not accessible- then make sure there is a route for the IP/IP subnet of the server IP through the vpn tunnel. You can do it by using route/netstat
example

```
netstat -nr | grep "147.163"
```

If route is not present you may have to add a route for this IP through the VPN tunnel. You can find the "route add.." or "ip route add ... " commands for this from google depending on your machine platform.

If the Ping shows the IP is pinging, we need to make sure the ssh service is running on the port 22. Just do a telnet and check

```
telnet <server_ip> 22
```

if the connection shows UP, in your case which shouldn't show UP btw :)as you got a timeout already. Then problem can be 
(1) ssh service not running
(2) any firewall blocking your connection
You may have to get in touch with the ADMIN in that case.

===== Update =========

I guess your ping itself is failing.
Ping should show it is getting response.

```
example : 
XXXXXXX$ ping 216.58.217.174
PING 216.58.217.174 (216.58.217.174): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.217.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=43 time=273.068 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.174: icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=317.405 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.174: icmp_seq=2 ttl=43 time=361.682 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.217.174: icmp_seq=3 ttl=43 time=266.436 ms
```

Check for the routes in your machine using route or netstat.
Possibilities :

- server is down
- Proper route is not present for the IP/subnet of the ssh server through VPN tunnel

Comment: The command 147.163.26.244 ping  gives me: PING 147.163.26.244 (147.163.26.244) 56(84) bytes of data.   telnet  147.163.26.244 22 gives: Trying 147.163.26.244...  and  it is still running. What can I Deduce?

Comment: Server was down. Now it's ok. Thanks!